# Installing electrical sub-panel at future above-ground pool

Tags: electrical

Sorry to beat a dead horse with this subject but I'm a little unclear when it comes to the issue of installing additional ground rods. So here's my situation....The pool has not been installed yet but I've run an 8/2 UF-B line (not live yet) that will run about 130-140' from the house breaker panel to a 2 circuit sub-panel at the pool location. One circuit will be dedicated to the pool pump and the other circuit will be for general use since the pool is so far away from the house. My general use outlet box is connected about 6" away from the sub-panel via water-tight conduit and a GFCI outlet. The pool pump circuit will be connected with the same type conduit and GFCI outlet but will be about 6' from the sub-panel. Both outlets will be more than 5' from the edge of the pool. So, besides my question of needing an additional ground rod, if not, is the 12 gauge ground in the 8/2 line sufficient back to the house panel?

Answer (score 1):

This gets seemingly odd because of the Article 680 rules specific to pools and other water features.

First off, pool feeders are not allowed to be direct buried as per 680.25 and the Exception thereto which AFAICT doesn't apply to outdoor cabling, so unless your AHJ disagrees with me and applies the exception, you'll have to dig up the existing UF and re-run it in conduit (either red brass RMC or IMC, or Schedule 80 PVC or RTRC-XW IF you protect the aboveground portions from physical damage).

Second, your pool will have an equipotential grid of some type associated with it (at least for the pool surround, if not under the pool itself) -- this is a Code *requirement* to avoid hazardous step potentials in the pool area.  **All** conductive things directly associated with the pool (i.e. within 5' of it or part of the water circulating system) must be bonded to this grid as per 680.26 -- this includes the pool pump motor.  From there, the pool equipotential grid is connected to the regular bonding system by the pool pump motor's EGC.  While the AHJ can't make you put a direct link between the equipotential grid and the subpanel ground bus in, it's a good idea to do so, using the same 8AWG that's used for the equipotential grid.

Last but not least, your 8/2 should have a 10AWG ground -- 12AWG copper ground wires are only good for 20A circuits, max.